# mget cannot get primitive function like get

Tags: r

I can use `get` to get primitive function, like:

```
get('$') 
.Primitive("$")
```

However, `mget` failed:

```
mget('$')
Error: value for ‘$’ not found
```

Why? How to fix this?

Comment: Try specifying `inherits = TRUE`.

Comment: @thelatemail If only that were true...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default for `get` is to use `inherits = TRUE` (I think, based on the docs, for historical reasons), while the default for `mget` is `inherits = FALSE`. So using `inherits = TRUE` should make it work like `get`.

If you'd like a *really* detailed (but also very very good) dive into exactly what's happening here read [this](http://blog.obeautifulcode.com/R/How-R-Searches-And-Finds-Stuff/). Or just skip to the "Map of the World" section, and remember that `$`, being a primitive function, is in the environment of the of the base namespace (package:base, essentially).